# Querying a form in Django 1.5

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I need to make a CRUD operation over a form a I have in Django, but i'm confused in how to achieve this. I mean there are different situations and approaches to what I'm looking for.

Consider this form:

```
class UsuarioFidetel(models.Model):
"""
Modelo de usuario fidetel
"""

usuario = models.CharField(max_length=30)
id_usuario = models.IntegerField()
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
apellido = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
tipo_cedula = models.CharField(max_length=1, null=True)
cedula = models.CharField(max_length=9, null=True)
fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
sexo = models.CharField(max_length=1, null=True)
correo = models.EmailField(max_length=254, null=True)
estado_civil = models.CharField(max_length=1, null=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.nombre
```

There are several users on db with these fields stored. Now, i need to query this from a different form and show data of the user and even edit this data/user.

I already have this on models.py, and everything on my template and it's working ok, but I need to make this query, i know I should use this:

```
usuarios = UsuarioFidetel.objects.all().order_by("nombre").values('nombre')
```

But I'm quite confused on how to implement this, or maybe should I use `queryset`?

Any example or ideas are welcome.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

My forms.py:

```
class FormularioUsuarioFidetel(FormularioPersona):
"""
Clase que contiene el formulario que permite ingresar y modificar los 
datos del usuario de fidetel
"""    
usuariofide = forms.CharField()
sexo = ChoiceField(required=True, 
                   choices=SEXO_OPCIONES, 
                   error_messages={'required': 'El Sexo es un campo obligatorio'})
estado_civil = ChoiceField(required=True, 
                           choices=ESTADO_CIVIL_OPCIONES, 
                           error_messages={'required': 'El Estado Civil es un campo obligatorio'})

class Meta:
    model = UsuarioFidetel
    fields = ('nombre', 'apellido', 'tipo_cedula', 'cedula', 'correo', 'sexo', 'estado_civil', 'fecha_nacimiento')

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(FormularioUsuarioFidetel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['fecha_nacimiento'].widget.attrs = {'style':'width: 90px', 
                                                  'maxlength':'10'}
    self.fields['fecha_nacimiento'].required = True
    self.fields['fecha_nacimiento'].error_messages = {'required': 'La Fecha de Nacimiento es un campo obligatorio'}

def clean_fecha_nacimiento(self):
    """
    Método que valida que la fecha de nacimiento no sea posterior a la fecha 
    actual

    @return: Un mensaje de error si la fecha de nacimiento es posterior a la 
    fecha actual
    """
    fecha_nacimiento = str(self.cleaned_data['fecha_nacimiento'])

    if fecha_nacimiento > str(datetime.datetime.now().date()):
        raise forms.ValidationError(u"La fecha de nacimiento no puede ser posterior a la fecha actual")

    return self.cleaned_data['fecha_nacimiento']
```

My views.py

```
def consultar_usuario_fidetel(request):
"""
Muestra el formulario de consulta de datos del usuario de fidetel

@return: El formulario de consulta de datos del usuario de fidetel
"""

usuario_fidetel = request.session['usuario_fidetel']

if(not usuario_fidetel.tipo_cedula):
    return render_to_response('fidetel/inicio.html', 
                              { }, 
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))

sexo = dict(SEXO_OPCIONES)[usuario_fidetel.sexo]
estado_civil = dict(ESTADO_CIVIL_OPCIONES)[usuario_fidetel.estado_civil]

return render_to_response('fidetel/consultar_usuario_fidetel.html', 
                          { 'usuario_fidetel': usuario_fidetel,
                            'sexo': sexo,
                            'estado_civil': estado_civil }, 
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))

@autenticacion_fidetel_requerida
@permiso_requerido([PERMISOS_FONDO['MODIFICAR_USUARIO_FIDETEL']])
```

Let me explain myself better, with this form and view, I can edit data from the user which is logged in to the webapp, now, what I need, is to load all users stored from model `UsuarioFidetel` into db, regardless of who's logged in to the application, maybe searching by it's name or something...

If you need further explanation let me know, thanks.

Comment: Not sure this is answerable? Are you asking people to design a form for you or do you have a specific issue?

Comment: No, I actually have this form working, I just need to query data which is saved by this form (user registration) and check it, make changes to it, etc... I mean make changes to data already inserted from this form into db, this is just my model.py, if you need further code or explanation I can Edit my question, thanks.

Comment: you can add form and view ?

Comment: Ok, i'm updating the question.

Comment: you need to load all your UsuarioFidetel and applyed CRUD operation on this user Tell me if I'm wrong ?

Comment: Yes, that is, exactly

Comment: Already Creates, but I need to update (access to all users, not just the one logged in) and of course delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

views.py
    #get all users and inject in users.htm

```
 def users(request):    
    users=UsuarioFidetel.objects.all()
    context = {'users': users}
    return render(request, 'users.html', context)
```

in the  users.html

## list of all of users with 2 links delet and edit

```
{% for user in users %}
<li>{{user.usuario}}<span>{{user.apellido}}</span></li> 
<a  href="{% url 'editUser' user.id %} "></a>
<a  href="{% url 'deletetUser' user.id %}"></i></a>                 
{% endfor %}
```

what about this example you have idea now

Comment: Yes, well, I'm going to post my result, i'm doing the changes right now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are asking, because in django you can use [generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/) which will automate a lot of your daily work; all you need to do is configure them appropriately.

Since you already have a form, you can use [`CreateView`, `UpdateView`, `DeleteView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#model-forms), to take care of your `CRUD` operations.

For simply listing all objects, use [`ListView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#generic-views-of-objects), like this:

In `views.py`:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import UsuarioFidetel

class UsarioList(ListView):
    model = UsuarioFidetel
    template_name = 'all_list.html'
```

In your `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from yourapp.views import UsarioList

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^usario/$', UsarioList.as_view()),
)
```

In `all_list.html`, you'll get a variable `object_list`, which will be the list of all your objects, nicely paginated:

```
{% if object_list %}
    {% for obj in object_list %}
       {{ obj }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if is_paginated %}
        <div class="pagination">
            <span class="page-links">
                {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                    <a href="/usario?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">&lt;</a>
                {% endif %}
                <span class="page-current">
                    Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
                </span>
                {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                    <a href="/usario?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">&gt;</a>
                {% endif %}
            </span>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
    <p>No records found</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was trying this example (just for the record) but it's giving me error "'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'" from this line: url(r'^usuario/$', UsuarioList.as_view()),

Comment: Your example works now, lol, yes from now on i'm going to use generic views, think it's a better approach, thank you very much!